How to reliable check whether WSL is installed via C#?
How can I reliable check whether or not WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) is installed via C#, no matter the device' language or other stuff that might get in the way?

If you know what distribution you're after, like "ubuntu", you can interop this WslIsDistributionRegistered method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wslapi/nf-wslapi-wslisdistributionregistered) pretty easily, it will say true or false.

Invoke wsl --version and if it does not exist an error will be thrown.
var info = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "wsl",
    Arguments = "--version",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
};
var process = Process.Start(info);
process.WaitForExit();


You can use Powershell for this.
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux" | where State -eq Enabled;

From C#, you do it like this (after loading the correct Nuget packages)
using var ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Get-WindowsOptionalFeature")
  .AddParameter("Online")
  .AddParameter("FeatureName", "Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux");

var results = ps.Invoke();


Is this adaptable to use Process.Start() instead?

Well you could call powershell.exe with a script parameter, but why would you?

I tried using this command in the commandline itself, but it does not return anything. When I don't run it with admin rights, it throws an error.

Yes you need admin rights for it. You need to run the first command in Powershell, not a regular cmd command line.

I was running it in PowerShell. I got no output whatsoever with admin rights, and an error without.

If you got no output then it's not installed. You can remove the | where filter to get the result either way. If the feature is not available at all on your edition of Windows (maybe Windows Home?) then you still won't get any result.

When I tried the command, WSL apparently got uninstalled (from a different user on the device). Now I reinstalled it, but with the | where part, it still yields no results. If I remove that, I get a small list of items, including FeatureName, DisplayName, Description, RestartRequired, State, and CustomProperties.

It is possible to install it separately from the built-in Optional Features (via the MS Store for example) so maybe the user did it that way. If State is Disabled then it's not installed via the system and won't get updated with it.

It says State: Disabled in my case.
